# PyCharm: debug Django Rest Viewsets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pycharm

I have got the following viewset (same in the [Rest Framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)):

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Let's say this viewset is called by: `GET` `127.0.0.1:8000/api/user`

I want to set **breakpoints** and watch, how the code is executing when I request to that viewset from my web-interface. But I don't understand how to make my breakpoints to work.

I know that it is possible to debug django commands (that are inherited from `BaseCommand` and called by `python manage.py <command_name>`). I simply define in `Run/Debug configurations` Script - `manage.py` and script parameters - `<command_name>` and everything works like a charm.

Is it possible to Debug my viewsets somehow? I want my code to stop on my breakpoints when I call my viewset.

Comment: If you are using pycharm then you can also [set breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/types-of-breakpoints.html) after running the debugger, right?

Comment: start with debugging `as_view` of your view

Comment: @AKS and @dnit13 I haven't understood both of your answers. @AKS what the point of toggling breakpoints afterwards? @dnit13 Where to use `as_view`?

Comment: Setting breakpoints provides you flexibility into where you want to code to stop and when do you want to toggle and set a next breakpoint as you wish.

Comment: The point is that Debugger not stopping on my breakpoints. I toggled them on my viewset but the code simply executes and stops nowhere.

Comment: Are you using Pycharm community or professional edition?

Comment: @Fian Professional (trial)

Comment: to which line did you set the breakpoint? You need to set it somewhere inside the `list` method that you have implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Pycharm professional:

1. Run - Edit configurations
2. Click "+", select "Django server"
3. Enter name("Django debug server"), host (127.0.0.1) and port (8000), check if  right python interpreter is selected, click OK.
4. Run - Debug - Select your created debug configuration "Django debug server".
5. Set breakpoints, for your case, in UserViewSet list() method. All around, in all lines, to be sure.
6. Open 127.0.0.1:8000/api/user in any browser.
7. Debugger should stop at your breakpoints.

P.S. In №5 you can go deeper and set breakpoints to the django.core.handlers.base method get_response() that is handling requests to your server.

Comment: Thank you for PS (django.core.handlers.base) - because I have troubles with unexpected 401 response.